# How can I prove that the map $\mathbb T^2\to X$ where $X$ is this torus in $\mathbb R^3$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm given this mapping $f$ which maps $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$ from $S^1\times S^1$ to $((ax_1+b)y_2,(ax_1+b)x_2,ay_1)$ on the torus in $\mathbb R^3$ and need to show that this map is a homeomorphism. Essentially I need to show this map is continuous and also find its inverse and show that that is also continuous, but since this is within the topic of topology I'm unsure whether I need to show it by considering open sets? Or whether I can just say that each component of the image in $\mathbb R^3$ is continuous and so $f$ is continuous? How can I find its inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f$ is certainly continuous, because each component is a polynomial in the coordinates on $S^1 \times S^1$.

How to find the inverse? Well, you're given $a$ and $b$ (the minor and major radii) of the torus, and presumably someone already told you that $a < b$ because otherwise the claim is false.

So suppose you know that $(X,Y,Z)$ is on the torus, and you'd like to find $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ such that $f(x_1, ..., y_2) = (X, Y, Z)$.

Well, $ay_1 = Z$, so $y_1 = Z/A$.

Then $X^2 + Y^2 = (ax_1 + b)^2 (y_2^2 + x_2^2) = (ax_1 + b)^2$, so you can say that
$$
(ax_1 + b) = \pm \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}. 
$$
But since $b > a$, we know that $b + ax_1 \ge b - a \ge 0$, so actually
$$
(ax_1 + b) = + \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}. 
$$
So you can divide through by that (in the first two entries) to get $y_2$ and $x_2$.
And you can solve for $x_1$ by writing
$$
x_1 = \frac{1}{a} \left(\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} - b \right).
$$